# How to override public static function of parent theme through functions.php in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, overriding, overwrite

This is how the function is declared in parent theme and I would like to change the returning value logic, can anyone please guide me in the right direction?

I tried adding the function in `functions.php` with new logic and `add_action`, but that didn't help.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_calculate_price', array($this, 'ajax_calculate_price'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_calculate_price', array($this, 'ajax_calculate_price'));

public static function ajax_calculate_price( ) {
        $listing_id = $_POST['listing_id'];
        $tickets = isset($_POST['tickets']) ? $_POST['tickets'] : 1 ;


        $normal_price = (float) get_post_meta ( $listing_id, '_normal_price', true);
        $reservation_price  =  (float) get_post_meta ( $listing_id, '_reservation_price', true);
        $services_price = 0;
        if(isset($_POST['services'])){
            $services = $_POST['services'];
            $bookable_services = listeo_get_bookable_services($listing_id);
             $i = 0;
             foreach ($bookable_services as $key => $service) {
                $i++;
                if(in_array('service_'.$i,$services)) {
                  $services_price += (float) preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", '', $service['price']);

                }
             } 
        }
        $ajax_out['price'] = ($normal_price * $tickets) + $reservation_price + $services_price;
        wp_send_json_success( $ajax_out );
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, what did you need to achieve with that function.

Comment: Thank you :)
I want to change how the price is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

From your coding you are using listeo wordpress theme.
You are calling the function `listeo_get_bookable_services` which may not available in your themes `functions.php`. So in order to make that work include the class which has the function `listeo_get_bookable_services` in functions.php.

Comment: @Arpita ok. If above answer helps you. Please don't forgot to accept the answer.

Comment: Hey @droidDev, I end up doing it completely differently, so I am not sure if I can mark this as right answer.

Comment: @Arpita Ok No Prbolem and I have clearly stated that if the answer helps you.